# iterating a selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, each

This is a simple code to change the style of even numbered list elements but as a newbie, i really did not understand how the following if statement can be true and false. Because i think that key is always true. However, when i run the code, i see that it is not always true. Can someone explain why?

```
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $('ul#rubberSoul li').each(
      function(key)
        {
          if (key & 1) {
            $(this).addClass('rubberSoulEven');
          }
        }
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: `key & 1` will be truthy (`1`) for uneven numbers

Comment: @xdumaine Please don't edit posts to impose your own coding conventions on other users.

Comment: @meagar I was fixing an edit made by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` operator does a bitwise AND operation on each of the bits of two 32 bit expression (the operands). If the bit value from both the sides are 1, the result is `1`. Otherwise, the result is `0`. Bitwise ANDing any number  with 0 yields 0

For example , take this expression `x & y`

```
x value   y value   result 
-----------------------------
1         1         1
1         0         0
0         1         0
0         0         0
```

So in your case, it is going to check bit representation of `key` variable value & bit representation of `1` in your if condition and return the result of that.

```
operand1(key)  operand1-binary  operand2  operand2-binary   result 
------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 1              1           1                1
2                 10             1          01                0
3                 11             1          01                1
4                 100            1         001                0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i should study on javascript bitwise operators.

Comment: You are welcome ! I added some more details for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

key is index of each and **(key & 1)** is true for odd indexes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10501462)

Comment: How this is not answer?. The question is why code is working wrong, nor how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="rubberSoul ">
<li class="">One</li> # 0
<li class="">Two</li> # 1 
<li class="">Three</li> # 2
</ul>
```

Your `If` loop will show true for only the **second** statement (`<li class="">Two</li> # 1`) as it validates (`if (key & 1)`)